# PostgreSQL to PrestoSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, presto

I need to change my query from Postgres to Presto but I am getting an error which I don't understand - "mismatched input '&'. Expecting: expression"

My SQL query-

```
SELECT sub.custID, sum(coalesce(cast(devicecount as INT), 0)) as devicecount, data_attr3 FROM(
        SELECT  custID, data_attr1 as devicecount, split_part(data_attr3, '-', 2) data_attr3,
                RANK() OVER
                (
                    PARTITION by custID
                    ORDER BY collected_on desc
                ) AS rownum
        FROM tableA 
        ) sub
WHERE rownum = 1 and  string_to_array(data_attr3, ':') && '{0,1,2,4,5,16}'::text[]  group by 1, 3
```

I am getting an error at the last line where I am using "&&" but the error goes if I remove it.
The error then is not recognizing string_to_array and it cant recognize ::text[] on the last line. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always - [documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) is your friend. Presto has quite different syntax for handling arrays, so depending on Presto version you can try next:

```sql
select cardinality( -- count elements in array
        array_intersect( -- get arrays intersection
            split('1:2:3', ':'), -- split string on ':' as string_to_array
            array['0','1','2','4','5','16']) -- create varchar array
    ) > 0;
```

or

```sql
select arrays_overlap(
        split('1:2:3', ':'),
        array['0','1','2','4','5','16']
    );
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| true |